# Android 4.2.2 incoming call broadcast

Tags: android, call, broadcast

we have problem with incomming call broadcast on newest OS Android 4.2.2.

We are developing app, which should mute ringing for some contacts. It works fine on older systems, but on OS 4.2.2 the device rings for about 1-2 seconds until we are able to mute it.

This happens only when the device is in sleep mode (screen is off). Is the broadcast on this system delayed in some way? Has anybody experienced similar problem to this? Thank you for any reply.

EDIT: After some experiments (on Nexus 4) we found this: when we turn Wi-Fi off, the problem disapear so maybe Wi-fi use too much cpu time when turning on again from sleep (it's only hypothesis). And other think we found: it's happen about 3 times of 4 attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very nice, but solved by this:

for contacts we want to mute, set silent ringtone (it's empty 1s ogg file). Of course we backup previous ringtone and restore it when mute function is turned off.